# Increase resolution with word-cloud and remove empty border

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am using [word cloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/) with some txt files. How do I change [this example](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.py) if I wanted to 1) increase resolution and 2) remove empty border.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
"""
Minimal Example
===============
Generating a square wordcloud from the US constitution using default arguments.
"""

from os import path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

d = path.dirname(__file__)

# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'constitution.txt')).read()
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
# Open a plot of the generated image.
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can't increase the *resolution* of the image in `plt.show()` since that is determined by your screen, but you can increase the size. This allows it to scale, zoom, etc. without blurring. To do this pass dimensions to `WordCloud`, e.g.

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(text)
```

However, this just determines the size of the image created by `WordCloud`. When you display this using `matplotlib` it is scaled to the size of the plot canvas, which is (by default) around 800x600 and you again lose quality. To fix this you need to specify the size of the figure before you call `imshow`, e.g.

```
plt.figure( figsize=(20,10) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

By doing this I can successfully create a 2000x1000 high resolution word cloud.

For your second question (removing the border) first we could set the border to black, so it is less apparent, e.g.

```
plt.figure( figsize=(20,10), facecolor='k' )
```

You can also shrink the size of the border by using `tight_layout`, e.g.

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

The final code:

```
# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'constitution.txt')).read()
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=800).generate(text)
# Open a plot of the generated image.

plt.figure( figsize=(20,10), facecolor='k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

By replacing the last two lines with the following you can get the final output shown below:

```
plt.savefig('wordcloud.png', facecolor='k', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: final Constitution wordcloud]

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to use an image as a mask, make sure to use a big image to get better image quality.. I spent hours figuring this out.

Heres an example of a code snippet I used

```
mask = np.array(Image.open('path_to_your_image'))
image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(mask)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=800, background_color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", mask=mask
                     ,color_func = image_colors).generate_from_frequencies(x)

# Display the generated image:
plt.figure( figsize=(20,10) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)` does the job, reduces the space in the background, removing the excess padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `to_svg` and get a resolution however high you want.

```
    with open("Output.svg", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(wc.to_svg())
```

Try an example by appending these two lines to this [file](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/parrot.py), and the result is gorgeous.

(Other answers have addressed the border problem, and also the example doe not have a border.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you run into the issue of slower application while improving the resolution ie. in a web application, the [WordCloud documentation](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#:%7E:text=Larger%20canvases%20with%20make%20the%20code%20significantly%20slower)  advises that you utilize the **scale** parameter along with the canvas' *width & height* params to get a resolution & response time that works for your use case.

Answer (score -2):

Blurry wordclouds - I've been wrestling with this.  For my use, I found that too large a differential in the between the most frequent word occurrences and those with few occurrences left the lower-count words unreadable.  When I scaled the more frequent counts to reduce the differential, all the lower-frequency words were much more readable.