# How to generate a picture with high resolution using Python and word cloud

Tags: python, image, resolution, word-cloud

I am just studying Python and word cloud. But my picture is with low resolution. For example, the sample data is:

```
import os
import math
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator, get_single_color_func
a3='Python Python Python Matplotlib Matplotlib Seaborn Network Plot Violin Chart Pandas Datascience Wordcloud Spider Radar Parrallel Alpha Color Brewer Density Scatter Barplot Barplot Boxplot Violinplot Treemap Stacked Area Chart Chart Visualization Dataviz Donut Pie Time-Series Wordcloud Wordcloud Sankey Bubble'
```

and my code is:

```
building = np.array(Image.open("C://******/house.png"))
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="GhostWhite",width=800, height=800, margin=2,collocations=False,
                  mask=building,font_step=2).generate(a3)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7), facecolor='k')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

Here is the house picture I use in my code:

[image]

Then, here is my result:

[image]

You can see the resolution is pretty low. Actually, this is just a small sample data. When I use my real data, I have a picture that is much worse than this.

How can I improve the resolution?

Comment: Seems the same question, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786534/increase-resolution-with-word-cloud-and-remove-empty-border

Comment: Hi, Thanks. i already saw and tried this method. Not very good.

Comment: What problem there ? I seems to be the same task. Or not ?

Comment: When I tried that way, I have got a picture with the same quality above. It is not as good as the picture in that answer. I have no idea why.

Comment: It seems pyplot needs higher resolution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my observation, you have to increase width=800, height=800

and
`plt.figure(figsize = (16,9))` for 2k resolution or you can increase it.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I have tried different ways. I think this is the effective one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `to_svg` and get a resolution however high you want.

```
    with open("Output.svg", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(wc.to_svg())
```

Try an example by appending these two lines to this [file](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/parrot.py), and the result is gorgeous.