# Creating user-defined word cloud in python with dash.plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash, word-cloud

I'm totally new in this world.

I have checked a lot of sites and in here but can't seem to find a way to a solution.

I need to create a word cloud in python with dash.plotly.

The requirements is the following:
I have a data set with several .txt files.

I need to be able to search for keyword and then the wordcloud should reflect all the sentences where the keyword occurs from my txt files.

Is that possible?

Best regards.

I tried researching on several sites. Since i'm new in this world not a lot mad sense hence why i'm in here to maybe get som guidance.

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361789/best-way-to-generate-a-high-quality-word-cloud-image-for-a-dash-app). You might need to use another lib to generate a wordcloud image, and use a plotly go.Image in your dash interface. Separate the wordcloud generation image in a function that you can call within a dash callback when a word input value change.